# Sphinx automodule: failed to import module

Tags: django, python-sphinx, django-sphinx

I'm learning **Sphinx** to document my **Django** project.

My project structure is like

```
app
|- docs
   |- build
   |- source
      |- conf.py
      |- index.rst
   |- make.bat
   |- Makefile
|- src
   |- authentication
      |- __init__.py
      |- models.py
      |- ...
   |- myapp
      |- __init__.py
      |- settings.py
      |- wsgi.py
   |- manage.py
```

in the `app/docs/source/conf.py, the path to find doc is set as

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../src'))
```

and **index.rst** has content

```
App's documentation!
=============================================

.. automodule:: manage
   :members:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:



Indices and tables
==================

* :ref:`genindex`
* :ref:`modindex`
* :ref:`search`
```

on running

```
make html
```

It generates blank documentation page with default content and no content from the Django application.

I have many applications created and each application contains many files. I want to auto-generate documentation from the docstring throughout the Django application.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this https://medium.com/@sschannak/sphinx-for-django-documentation-2b9c900c6cfa. It's look like you are missing the django setup and you need to add `.. automodule::` for you project modules that you want to document.

Comment: Thanks. But can I automate documenting all files of the app included in `INSTALLED_APPS` list? There are lot of files and it will be difficult adding all views, models, etc separately.

Comment: I have never used it, but take a look at https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html